# Are these expressions linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, summation

I have two formulae written in summation notation. How can I determine if these are linear or not. I presume they're not linear but I can't proof it mathematically.

$$\sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^2 w_i x_j$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \ w_i x_i$$

Thank you.

Comment: Linear in what?

Comment: sorry forgot that part. linear in x?

Comment: yes. They are linear in $x$. But not in $(w,x)$.

Comment: The second is just the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Definition).  So we immediately see that it is linear in $x$ *and* in $w$.

Comment: @PRCube If the first is linear in $x$ then $$\sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=1}^2 w_i(x_j+y_j) = \sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=1}^2 w_ix_j + \sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=1}^2 w_iy_j$$ Is this true?  Can you (dis)prove it?